# Ember: property in array controller computed from property of item controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a typical `ArrayController`/`ObjectController` setup as follows:

```
App.PlayersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'playerItem',
  visibleCount: function(){
     //How do I compute this property?
  }.property(...),
});


App.PlayerItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: 'players',
  visible: function(){
     ...
  }).property('...')
})
```

The `visible` property is computer on the `PlayerItemController`, but I want to have a global count of visible players from the `visibleCount` in the `PlayersController`. How do I achieve this?

Here's what I've tried:

```
visibleCount: function(){
  return this.get('content').filter(function(p){
    return p.get('visible')
  }).length;
 }.property('content.@each.visible'),
```

This doesn't work, as `p.get('visible')` returns `undefined` every time and the property returns `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trigger this completely off the array controller instance itself, since that's where the `itemController` is defined.  Any time you attempt to iterate the `this` inside the array controller you will get the individual item controllers.

This makes just as much since when you think about it in the context of the template.  If you iterate the controller, you get the item Controllers

```
{{#each item in controller}}
  yay I have an item controller
{{/each}}
```

whereas if you just iterate the model/content you just get that record back

```
{{#each item in model}}
  boo, boring model
{{/each}}

App.PlayersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'playerItem',
  visibleItems: Em.computed.filterBy('','visible', true),
  // you don't need this below, you could just do, `visibleItems.length` in the template
  visibleCount: Em.computed.alias('visibleItems.length'),

  // showing off getting item controller
  randomProp: function(){
    this.forEach(function(ic){
      console.log(ic.get('visible'));
    });
  }.property('@each.visible')
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dalazawe/1/edit

It's really cool if you think of it in the way it's implemented.  Essentially the array controller overrides how it returns items from the controller to you.  When you attempt to get `objectAt(1)`, if you've defined an `itemController` it will wrap the underlying object in the `itemController` and return it.  Or if you haven't defined an `itemController`, it just returns the object to you.  Most people are stuck on it just being how it's implemented in the template but that's just half of it, it's how the array controller returns objects to you.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dalazawe/2/edit

Comment: Worked like a charm. Great answer that clears up many things. Side question: what does `Em.computed.filterBy('','visible', true)` do? Specifially, passing an empty string as a first parameter?

Comment: the first parameters is the sub property to key off, but we wanted to key off this, so we send in ''.